# basic auth URLSession POST

Tags: swift, post, basic-authentication, urlsession

Hi developers im trying to do a request like my postman using basic auth with an Username & password, but i can't archieve, heres what i have done so far

this is how postman look like
[image]
[image]

first i tryied this way

```
func postDataFormRequest(resource: TokenRequest, completion: @escaping (Result<Token, NetworkError>) -> Void) {  

    let headers = [  
        "Username": "example_api",  
        "Password": "example_api_password",  
        "Content-Type": "application/form-data"  
    ]  

//this information comes from TokenRequestStruct once i call it form my VC  
    let body = "grant_type=\(resource.grant_type)&username=\(resource.username)&password=\(resource.password)"  

    guard let url = URL(string: "example/") else { return }  

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)  
    request.httpMethod = HTTPMethods.POST  
    request.timeoutInterval = 60  
    request.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)  
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers  

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in  

        guard let data = data, error == nil else {  
            completion(.failure(.domainError))  
            return  
        }  

        let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Token.self, from: data)  
        if let result = result {  
            DispatchQueue.main.async {  
                completion(.success(result))  
            }  
        } else {  
            DispatchQueue.main.async {  
                completion(.failure(.decodingError))  
            }  
        }  
    }.resume()  
}
```

using this method response =

```
CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.
Error=-25300, query={
    atyp = http;
    class = inet;
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    ptcl = http;
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    sdmn = "oauth2/client";
    srvr = "3.216.253.237";
    sync = syna;
}
```

tried to fix it by using arbitrary loads = YES
didn't work

Second way

```
static func getPostString(params:[String:Any]) -> String  
{  
    var data = [String]()  
    for(key, value) in params  
    {  
        data.append(key + "=\(value)")  
    }  
    return data.map { String($0) }.joined(separator: "&")  
}  

static func formData(url:URL, params:[String:Any], finish: @escaping ((message:String, data:Data?)) -> Void)  
    {  
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)  
        request.httpMethod = "POST"  

        let postString = self.getPostString(params: params)  
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)  

        var result:(message:String, data:Data?) = (message: "Fail", data: nil)  
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in  

            if(error != nil)  
            {  
                result.message = "Fail Error not null : \(error.debugDescription)"  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                result.message = "Success"  
                result.data = data  
            }  

            finish(result)  
        }  
        task.resume()  

}
```

usage:
in my VC

```
let dict:[String:String] = ["username": view.emailField.text ?? "", "password": view.passField.text ?? "", "grant_type": "password"]  

            let url = URL(string: “example”)!  
            NetworkManager.formData(url: url, params: dict) { (message, data) in  
                print(message)  
                print(data)
```

didn't work either it says Mising grant_type

third way:

```
public static func LoginGenerateTokenPOST(userName: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {  
       let baseUrl = "example"  


        let url = URL(string: "\(baseUrl)example")!  
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)  
        request.setValue("application/form-data", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")  
        //request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")  
        request.setValue("example_api", forHTTPHeaderField: "example_api_password")  
        request.httpMethod = "POST"  



        let postString = "username=\(userName.lowercased())&password=\(password.sha256())&grant_type=password"  
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)  

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in  
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error  
                 completion(false)  
                print("error")  
                return  
            }  

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors  
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")  
                completion(false)  


            }  

                do {  
                if let convertedJsonIntoDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSDictionary {  

                   print(convertedJsonIntoDict)  



                }  
            }  
            catch let error as NSError {  
                completion(false)  
                print(error.localizedDescription)  
            }  

        }  
        task.resume()  

        }
```

this is my third function didn't work either

so my question is:

what is the best way to use basic auth URLSession POST, what did i do wrong in any of the 3 cases?, or all 3 are useless

Comment: If you’re using postman, why don’t you tap the “code” button and take a look at the code it generates for Swift. FWIW, your postman specified basic authentication, but none of these specify an `Authorization` header (where the value is user:password base-64 encoded). See [HTTP Basic Authentication: Client side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side) for info.

Comment: Also, are you wed to `application/form-data`? Preparing an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request is easier, and I bet your web service will accept it.

Comment: Finally, is your web service _really_ expecting both Basic auth _and_ the userid/password in the body of the request? Usually you’d see one or the other...

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, yes my WS expect basic auth and user/password in body

Comment: thank you so much it work using the "code" part in postman!!! thanks!!!